# How can i use count to see the "messages" column count on "hours" Column between a month in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I want to count the messages on each hours separated with column date, I write this query but it shows 1 messages for each duplicate hour, could anyone help? Thanks

```
Select MsgCount,ReadTime 
From (Select Count(MsgID) MsgCount, 
      LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), mDate, 100), 7)) as ReadTime
      FROM (Select  ReadDate as mDate,
            Convert (TIME, ReadDate) as ReadTime,MessageID as MsgID 
            From QUEUE_BOOKINGQUEUE 
            WHERE MessageID like '%Transaction%'
            AND ReadDate BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30') 
      s1
      Group by mDate
) A
Group by MsgCount,ReadTime
Order by 2
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That query contains lots of product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it worked with me as this picture there is no duplication
so, if you want to remove the grouping it will be like this:

```
Select MsgCount,ReadTime 
From (Select Count(MsgID) MsgCount, 
      LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), mDate, 100), 7)) as ReadTime
      FROM (Select  ReadDate as mDate,
            Convert (TIME, ReadDate) as ReadTime,MsgID as MsgID 
            From QUEUE_BOOKINGQUEUE 
    )  s1
      Group by mDate,s1.MsgID
) A
```

Comment: Yes seems there is no duplication, i have added the date:

Comment: Select MsgCount,ReadTime,ReadDate From 
(Select Count(MsgID) MsgCount, 
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), mDate, 100), 7)) as ReadTime,
CONVERT(DATE,mDAte) as ReadDate
  FROM
(Select  ReadDate as mDate,
 Convert (TIME, ReadDate) as ReadTime,MessageID as MsgID From QUEUE_BOOKINGQUEUE 
     WHERE MessageID like '%Transaction%'
  AND ReadDate BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30')s1
  Group by mDate
  ) A
  Group by MsgCount,ReadTime,ReadDate
Order by 3,2

Comment: Thanks, Now I want to remove the minutes, to see the messages per hour, whats your idea

Comment: Use   Select MsgCount,DATEPART(HOUR, ReadTime),ReadDate

Comment: i see the hour and date have duplicate after adding this, each row has 1 message , i need to see count of message on 1 row with 1 hour and 1 dateThe messageID is uniq, 
So do we need to change COUNT with sum?